# Deploying Azure Function (isolated process) to Azure using Azure DevOps is not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, .net-5, azure-function-app

Currently Microsoft has introduced a new way to treat azure functions called isolated process and it's the only way to run Azure functions on .NET5.

I am trying to deploy a function app that is already running correctly on my local machine to Azure Func app through Azure DevOps. It deployed successfully but the functions don't work.

First in the deployment task I can't see .NET 5 appears as shown:

[image]

But I can see in the link here that the .NET 5 is supported as preview:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#languages

After deploying, I can see this error:

[image]

But I changed the configuration to this:

[image]

Also the function shown this error:

[image]

Also I can see that the function has seen as running on .NET 5 from here:

[image]

So not sure how to deploy this correctly. I know that the isolated process functions are just need the azure functions tools + running command line so not sure how to deploy it and also Microsoft didn't have any tutorial or doc about how to deploy it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution for that. The problem was that Microsoft isn't supported running Isolated process functions on Linux plans.

Also as shown below, you can't create Isolated process functions from Azure portal yet (17/03/2021) so i had to create it myself as shown below:

```
az group create --name {resoucrce-group} --location {location}
```

Then

```
az storage account create --name {storage-name} --location {location} --resource-group {resoucrce-group} --sku Standard_LRS
```

Then create the function:

```
az functionapp create --resource-group {resoucrce-group} --consumption-plan-location {location} --runtime dotnet-isolated --runtime-version 5.0 --functions-version 3 --name {name} --storage-account {storage-name}
```

And now from the DevOps portal you can deploy a normal App Function on windows and here we go.

Comment: Just had the exactly same problem as you, it looks like it is still not possible to create Isolated process functions from Azure portal.

Comment: It is now possible to do this by the portal, however you need to make one single config adjustment after the resource has been created (See Frank's solution below).

Answer (score 1):

After creating you Azure Function App you can change **FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME** and set it to `dotnet-isolated` in the Configuration panel.

[image]